# How to name (numbering) the cover page

Tags: pdf, page-numbering, covers

I want to create a pdf like this...

[image]

I know that using \pagenumbering we can switch between (i, ii) and (1, 2, 3)... but how to name a specific page? particularly the cover.

*Further comments:*

Take as an example the following code and look the page numeration when is opened with acrobat reader.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{center}
{\Huge COVER PAGE}
\end{center}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{\Huge This is title of my document}
\end{center}
The first pages of the book are numbered with roman numbers (i, ii, ...). 
The numeration changes to arabic numbers from introduction.
\newpage
\lipsum[1-12]
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I assume, that this is something which has to be inserted into the `\pdfcatalog` etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, this is 'tricky'. Page names are page labels in the sense of PDF. One has to insert a `PageLabels` object into the pdfcatalog and enable `pdfpagelabels=true` for the `hyperref` package.

There a label prefixes, specified with the PDF command `/P` -- here set to 'Cover'

The syntax is as follows

```
/Nums[ 0 << /P (Cover) >>
        1 << /S /D >>
      ]
```

This will set the first page (0) as cover and consecutive ones will be shown as 'decimals' `/D`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\begin{document}

\pdfcatalog{%
  /PageLabels << /Nums [ 0 << /P (Cover) >>% 
  1 << /S /D >>%   
  ]
  >>
}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Start}
\blindtext[40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update ... much easier solution

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}



\newcommand{\CoverName}{Cover}%


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}%
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\CoverName}
\begin{center}
\Huge COVER PAGE
\end{center}
\cleardoublepage

% Switch to roman numbering
\pagenumbering{roman}



\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{\Huge This is title of my document}
\end{center}
The first pages of the book are numbered with roman numbers (i, ii, ...). 
The numeration changes to arabic numbers from introduction.

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\blindtext[10]
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}%  Change later on to more appropiate style
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[20]
\chapter{More stuff}
\end{document}
```

It requires the Adobe Reader feature 'show logical page numbers' to be activated.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer this could be a solution. But the numeration do not coincides, for example, the chapter 1 starts at page 3 (and this numeration is in the paper) but the page in the pdf menu is 2.

Comment: @Julian: I will look after it

Comment: @Julian: The `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and `\pagenumbering{Roman}` will screw up the internal counting

Comment: yes, a method that combines arabic and roman numbers with the pagelabels could be interesting.

Comment: @Julian: I updated the answer with a much easier and in my point of view working version

Comment: Ohh! ok, this is new for me.

Comment: The simplified solution works wonders! I would remove the complex solution, or put it below the simple one. By the way, in my experience it seems to be important that the redefinition of the command occurs after \pagestyle, for some reason.