# How to show proper page numbers

Tags: page-numbering

How can I show double numbers (for example iii, 5/229) as in this  book

[image]

Comment: Is this a TeX related question at all?

Comment: Your question sounds like it's about how to change settings of a pdf viewer, rather about anything related to TeX, LaTeX, and friends. If this impression is incorrect, please let us know what the connection to TeX and friends may be.

Comment: Do you mean a solution like renewing `\thepage` for viewers that support it (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205446/how-to-name-numbering-the-cover-page/205454#205454)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `\usepackage{hyperref}`  and the pagestyles like `\pagenumbering{roman}`(i,ii,...), `\pagenumbering{arabic}`(1,2,...) or `\pagenumbering{Roman}`(I,I,...).

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref} %https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=de <---------necessary package

\begin{document}
% page numbers: i,ii,...
\pagenumbering{roman} % small roman numbers <---------------------------(style i,ii,...)
\pagestyle{empty}%don't show page number

\textbf{TITEL}
\cleardoublepage %\newpage

% page numbers: 1,2,...
\pagenumbering{arabic}                % arabic numbers <-----------------(style 1,2,...)
\pagestyle{plain}% show page numbers again
Change pagenumbering style to arabic!

Your text. Page 1.
\cleardoublepage %\newpage
Next page here.
\cleardoublepage %\newpage

% page numbers: I,II,...
\pagenumbering{Roman} % big roman numbers <-----------------------------(Style: I,II,...)
Change pagenumbering style to Roman. For example appendix...

\cleardoublepage %\newpage
End.
\end{document}
```

Solution: **Collage** of the different pages with different numbering:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `lastpage` package with `fancyhdr`.

Then voilà !

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Comment: This will not show the style on the PDF viewer menu however, it changes the text displayed in the footer only