# Page with table of contents - page number

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I need to add a roman page number on the page with table of contents. My table of contents is long and has two pages but a page number appears only for the second page. Is it possible to enforce page number for the first page too?

Tereza

Comment: Welcome! Please add a minimal working example(MWE) -> https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/124842. Maybe the following could help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352724/124842 (\pagenumbering{Roman})

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks the second link helped me :)

Comment: If the question and the answer (in the link) helped you, you can upvote both (if you like). Is the problem solved ? Could the question here be closed? https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote

Comment: @Bobyandbob: calling for upvotes? ;-) (By the way: The OP is still beyond 15 rep, so he/she can't upvote yet )

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Nevertheless i think the question could be cloesed!?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Yes, it could, but I have no idea how :D